# How to make output more readable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, output, readability

I wrote the following code which prints prime numbers up to the desired number.

```
def prime_number(number1):
    for desired_num in range(1,int(number1)+1):
       if desired_num > 1:
          for i in range(2,desired_num):
              if (desired_num % i) == 0:
              break
          else:
              print(desired_num)
number2 = int(raw_input ("Enter any number :- "))
print "Prime numbers between 1 and", number2, "are :-"
prime_number(number2)
```

The output I get is similar to the following one, which becomes very cumbersome for a list with many numbers.

```
2   
3  
5  
7
```

The output I want is similar to the following one.

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to get the desired output?

Comment: There's always `print(desired_num, end=' ')`. Ugly hack for what you probably want tho. I just re-read the code. Remove the print in the function, and return a list so that `prime_number` returns a iterator instead.

Comment: `print(desired_num, end=' ')` is Python 3 — OP has tagged their question [python-2.7] and has one `print` as a statement line in the code they showed ... in the context of Python 2 a more relevant answer would be `print desired_num,` (note the ending comma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be better if using an array to store those prime numbers, then print it out.

```
import time

def prime_number(number1):
    primes = []
    for desired_num in range(1,int(number1)+1):
       if desired_num > 1:
          for i in range(2,desired_num):
              if (desired_num % i) == 0:
                  break
          else:
              primes.append(desire_num)
    return primes

number2 = int(raw_input ("Enter any number :- "))
print "Prime numbers between 1 and", number2, "are :-"
print(prime_number(number2))
```

Comment: In the append statement change the variable to `desired_num`

Answer (score 3):

To achieve your goal (have formatted output) you have to introduce some changes to your code, in other words, make it "more pythonic":

```
import time
from pprint import pprint, pformat
from typing import Iterable


def prime_number(number1):
    """
    generator
    :rtype: Iterable[int]
    :type number1: int
    """
    for desired_num in range(1, int(number1) + 1):
        if desired_num > 1:
            for i in range(2, desired_num):
                if (desired_num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                yield desired_num


number2 = int(raw_input("Enter any number :- "))
primes = pformat(list(prime_number(number2)))
print("Prime numbers between 1 and {} are :- {}".format(number2, primes))
```

What I used here is a *pipe*: `pformat(list(prime_number(...)))` generator -> list [1, 2, 3] -> text '[1, 3, ]'.
Then I put the text and `number2` into a *formatted* string, and sent to print.

If you are beginner in python and don't familiar with the `generators` concept, you may rewrite the `prime_number` function to use a simple `.append` to a list instead of yielding it and then return the whole list.

Comment: If I input a number >= 73, it doesn't give output in the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Use `append` to a new list:

```
import time
def prime_number(number1):
    l=[]
    for desired_num in range(1,int(number1)+1):
       if desired_num > 1:
          for i in range(2,desired_num):
              if (desired_num % i) == 0:
              break
          else:
              l.append(desired_num)
    print(l)
number2 = int(raw_input ("Enter any number :- "))
print "Prime numbers between 1 and", number2, "are :-"
start = time.time()
prime_number(number2)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea would be to store the list of primes in a python built-in list and then after all simple print it in your favorite format! As simple as that.

```
def prime_number(number1):
    primes = [] # An empty list here, that will be populated with primes!
    for desired_num in range(1,int(number1)+1):
       if desired_num > 1:
          for i in range(2,desired_num):
              if (desired_num % i) == 0:
                  break
          else:
              primes.append(desired_num)
    print "[" + ",".join(map(str, primes)) + "]" 

number2 = int(raw_input ("Enter any number :- "))
print "Prime numbers between 1 and", number2, "are :-"
primes = prime_number(number2)
```

Comment: @skaul05 I'm sorry, that's my mistake, and thanks for your edit

Answer (score 0):

You can take two ways to print. Either store it in a list and then print or print it serially.

**Approach 1** `Use list and then print it as comma separated`:

```
import time
def prime_number(number1):
    output_list = list()
    for desired_num in range(1,int(number1)+1):
        if desired_num > 1:
           for i in range(2,desired_num):
               if (desired_num % i) == 0:
                   break
           else:
               output_list.append(desired_num)
    return output_list
number2 = int(raw_input ("Enter any number :- "))
print "Prime numbers between 1 and", number2, "are :-"
output_list = prime_number(number2)
print (",".join(output_list))
```

**Approach 2** `Print the numbers in function itself serially using end`:

```
import time
def prime_number(number1):
    for desired_num in range(1,int(number1)+1):
        if desired_num > 1:
           for i in range(2,desired_num):
               if (desired_num % i) == 0:
                   break
           else:
               print(desired_num,end = " ")
  number2 = int(raw_input ("Enter any number :- "))
  print "Prime numbers between 1 and", number2, "are :-"
  prime_number(number2)
```

Comment: I think the else condition should be for FOR LOOP, not for the if condition. In approach 1 omitting comma ("," ) in the last print statement gives the desired output, but end in approach 2 gives an error in python 2.x

Comment: @Lucifer rightly said. Edited the solution Thanks!!